# Passing options to chrome driver selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to disable the output to the console for chrome. If I pass the --start-maximized option it works fine. I may have the wrong command?

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--silent"));
chrome = new ChromeDriver(_chromeservice,capabilities);
```

I also tried

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("silent");
 chrome = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Output

> Started ChromeDriver port=26703 version=23.0.1240.0
>   log=/Brett/workspace/TestNG/chromedriver.log
>   [1214/161331:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
>   [1214/161331:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
>   [1214/161331:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending
>   sendsBlockquote

Comment: Is silent a valid switch?  The way you are sending the switch is correct..Is disabling the logging is what you want?

Comment: If you are trying to pass switches directly to chrome, then `--silent` is not a valid switch. Here [link](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) is a list of valid switches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hinted by this [Chromedriver ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=116) (about the `silent` option), I looked in the source of [`ChromeDriverService.java`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.java), and found a reference to `"webdriver.chrome.logfile"`.

After adding `-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile="/dev/null"` to my `java` command, the logs became readable again: The usless ChromeDriver logs were gone, while the`System.out.println` calls and exceptions are still shown in the console.

I start `java` with the following parameters (Linux / Mac):

```
DIR=path/to/dir/containing/selenium/and/stuff
cd "$DIR" && java -cp "$DIR\
:$DIR/output\
:$DIR/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" \
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="$DIR/bin/chromedriver" \
-Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--disable-logging" \
-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile="/dev/null" \
AllTests
```

If you're on Windows:

```
set DIR=path\to\dir\containing\selenium\and\stuff
cd "%DIR%" && java -cp "%DIR%;%DIR%\output;%DIR%\bin\selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" ^
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="%DIR%\bin\chromedriver.exe" ^
-Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--disable-logging" ^
-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile=NUL ^
AllTests
```

---

Explanation for the composition of my classpath (`-cp`): My tests are located in a directory at "$DIR/output". The Selenium jar file is placed in "$DIR/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar". "AllTests" is the name of my class containing `public static void main(String[] args)` - this launches my tests.

The other parameters are self-explanatory, adjust it to your needs. For convenience (used in a shell/batch script), I've declared the common directory in a variable `DIR`.

Comment: Could you clearly explain how to use it in Java and Windows. I mean please add your code

Comment: @user2087450 See revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

When I was setting chrome up with

> ```
>   selenium-chrome-driver-2.48.2.jar
>   chromedriver 2.20
>   selenium-java-2.48.2.jar
> ```
>
> none of the above answers worked for me, 
>   Since I see some of the answers are a few years old, I will post what worked for me.
>
> ```
>     ChromeOptions chromeOptions = setupChromeOptions();
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "\\path\\chromedriver.log");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\path\\chromedriver.exe");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
>     driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
> ```

Comment: Bingo. I needed `logfile`, `args` AND `silentOutput`. The output looks so much nicer now. Proof that small things make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try "`--disable-logging`" instead.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-logging"));
chrome = new ChromeDriver(_chromeservice,capabilities);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it and it's still outputting the same information.

Comment: BTW what you see are not really errors per say, since they are not affecting chrome driver execution in any way, right?

Comment: No it does not effect the execution of any tests. I am just thinking down the line. After a while it will take up a lot of space in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

As of Selenium 3 at least, you can use ChromeDriverService and its inner class Builder to be able to launch the driver in silent mode.

A oneliner for that:

```
new ChromeDriver(new ChromeDriverService.Builder().withSilent(true).build());
```

The constructor is straight-forward, you create a new service builder setting silent to true (that's the critical part) and you finally build it into a ChromeDriverService which is required by ChromeDriver's constructor.