# Getting error after opening Chrome browser using Selenium-Webdriver on Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Steps**

1. Download selenium ChromeDriver for Windows 7 , 32 bit from [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/detail?name=chromedriver_win32_2.3.zip&can=2&q=)
2. Save in one folder and then Set path in Environment Variable
3. Write script in Ruby

```rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
WAIT = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 80)
driver.get 'URL'
sleep 3

WAIT.until { driver.switch_to.frame 'mainPage' }
d = WAIT.until { driver.find_element(:id, 'btnLogin') }
d.click
driver.quit
```

1. We are getting below error on console and script is opening chrome browser for 2 times

> Starting ChromeDriver (v2.3) on port 9516
>   [6388:400:0925/175026:ERROR:platform_thread_win.cc(127)] NOT
>   IMPLEMENTED [7988:7504:0925/175031:ERROR:textfield.h(173)] NOT
>   IMPLEMENTED

Is there any solution to remove above errors?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the correct version of [Chromedriver](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list) installed. For Chrome v27 and up, you'll need Chromedriver 2.X.X.

Answer (score 0):

They are just ChromeDriver's diagnostics messages, which are not any kind of error messages you need to worry about if they are not affecting your tests.

You can append `--silent` argument or use `SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation` (may not be available in Ruby binding) when starting ChromeDriver to suppress the information (first line). But there is no way to get rid of the errors (second and the third line), unless you raise a ticket to ChromeDriver's developers and ask them to change, here's the existing one 
[Issue 116: How to disable the diagnostic messages and log file from Chrome Driver?](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=116).

See answer [How to execute Selenium Chrome WebDriver in silent mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713908/1177636)

However, for anyone else using Java, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014883/1177636) might worth trying.