# Using chromedriver with selenium ubuntu

Tags: selenium

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
Command duration or timeout: 253 milliseconds.
 please help me for finding this.

Comment: Where is your code? How are you setting the path?

Comment: Please go through this link and ask a question properly: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you read the basic documentation - specified in the link of that error?

Comment: [Please read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to run java test you must provide the path to the "chromedriver" file to the "JVM".

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path_to_your_chromedriver ...
```

Comment: `chromedriver.exe`, that will surely work on Ubuntu...

Comment: Isn't there an equivalent for Ubuntu?  With FF you do not need an additional driver.  Anyway on the download page you can get an archive for Linux systems.

Comment: Yes there is, but without the ".exe" suffix. There is a slight difference in the commandline syntax, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886430/passing-options-to-chrome-driver-selenium/17014883#17014883 for a full example.

Comment: You are right, I fixed the command line.