# Passing options to chrome driver selenium in command line

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Default options for chrome driver in selenium don't work. I have to pass these arguments:

```
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
```

But I don't want to pass them on all clients, I want to set them on server.

According to this topic: [Passing options to chrome driver selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886430/passing-options-to-chrome-driver-selenium)

... trying this:

```
xvfb-run -a java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--headless"
```

... ang got:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '-Dwebdriver.chrome.args=--headless' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
```

What system arguments should I pass to java?

Comment: Use `xvfb-run -a java -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--headless"  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar`. ie. Pass the system properties to the java command and not as arguments to the main class of the JAR.

Comment: No error, but no effect. Looks like  webdriver.chrome.args are ignored.

Comment: You wrote that you don't want to set the options on the clients. Why is that?
Can't you use https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html#ChromeDriver-org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions-? Works perfectly okay for me when creating the WebDriver instance.

Comment: Piohen, I am using php facebook webdriver. 3 client scripts are already running in production. I have to refactor their code to pass options. But I don't need any options, this is a workaround. It is the better way to do this workaround in server config, not in repository.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Somehow I assumed this is Java. Good luck then!

Comment: On server side this is Java and my question is about it )